# Haskell Read (no instance)

Tags: haskell, instance, overloading, ghci

I am a Haskell beginner and have a weird question. Up until now everything has been going great, and I have been able to use Prelude read function normally. Now suddenly I have to constantly declare it's type in order to use it.

I always have to declare this or something similar in order to use it.

```
let r = read::String-> Int
```

I have tried restarting ghci thinking I have accidentally overloaded read but whenever I try using it normally as such

```
read "456"
```

I get the following error

```
No instance for (Read a0) arising from a use of `read'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Read () -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
  instance (Read a, Read b) => Read (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
  instance (Read a, Read b, Read c) => Read (a, b, c)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
  ...plus 25 others
In the expression: read "456"
In an equation for `it': it = read "456"
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: if you write r "456" instead, it works. You only restrict r, not read, with the "let".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, to solve your problem, you could specify the result you expect from `read` in one of a few ways:

First, by specifying the type of the result of the entire computation:

```
read "456" :: Int
```

Or by specifying the type of the function read:

```
(read :: String -> Int) "456"
```

To explain why this happens, the issue is that `read` is polymorphic in its result type. That is, there are many different `read` functions defined, and they are defined as part of a typeclass `Read`. The error gives you the explanation why:

```
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Read () -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
  instance (Read a, Read b) => Read (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
  instance (Read a, Read b, Read c) => Read (a, b, c)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
  ...plus 25 others
```

The `Read` typeclass is defined for many, many types, it says there are 28 instances defined in the error. It's defined for Int, and for Integer, and Double, and String, and countless others. And so in order for the compiler to know what instance of the typeclass to use, it needs to be able to infer that from the type of `read` that you specify. If you give it `:: String -> Int`, the compiler can figure it out.

To understand how this works, let's look at part of the type class for `Read`:

```
class Read a where
  read :: String -> a
```

So for a given type `a`, an instance of `Read a` must be defined in order for the function `read` to return a value of type `a`. So for `Int`, there is a definition for an instance of `Read Int`, and indeed there is in [GHC-Read](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Read.html). That instance defines how `read` works. Unfortunately, the instance is rather obtuse and relies on other functions and other such things, but for the sake of completeness, here it is:

```
instance Read Int where
  readPrec     = readNumber convertInt
  readListPrec = readListPrecDefault
  readList     = readListDefault
```

But, the important thing to realize is that this instance means that `read` will work for `Int`. But shortly after, there's this instance:

```
instance Read Double where
  readPrec     = readNumber convertFrac
  readListPrec = readListPrecDefault
  readList     = readListDefault
```

Oh dear. So `read` works for `Int` and for `Double`!

The Haskell language ensures the compiler will, usually, try to infer a unique type for a value or fail. There are some odd exceptions to this with some extensions to the language in GHC, but you have to remember here that Haskell is trying to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. If you don't specify somehow the type you're expecting from `read`, then the compiler could infer *any* type, but that might not be valid. You wouldn't want your code to suddenly start reading in floating point `Double`s or arbitrary precision `Integer`s where you previously expected to read in an `Int`, right?

In this case, not specifying the type merely caused the compiler to give up, it couldn't definitively answer the question you asked it to, which is, "Which instance of `Read` do I use?" And Haskell compilers *do not like guessing*. One way to prevent it from guessing is to use a value in a way that is unambiguous later, or to define a function that uses `read` unambiguously. For example, this function can be used in your code to avoid having to type `:: String -> Int`:

```
readInt :: String -> Int
readInt = read
```

The compiler can figure out which instance of `Read` it needs to use there, and in your code if you do:

```
readInt "456"
```

The compiler will know that `readInt` has type `String -> Int`, and thus `readInt "456"` has type `Int`. Unambiguous, just like Haskell likes it.

### Addendum

The syntax in GHCi is a bit different for defining things, so if you are using GHCi exclusively to play around with Haskell, I'd recommend you switch to loading .hs files and using the `:r` command to reload them. One problem with GHCi is that you have to define everything with "let" which will start to feel strange when you start writing programs, where top level definitions don't need that. Another problem is the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) which, frankly, is just kind of weird and quirky and it's not worth going into detail about it here.

Anyhow, the syntax for defining `readInt` above in GHCi is simple, though there are two ways (equivalent). You already know one, which is to do it like this:

```
let readInt = read :: String -> Int
```

The other way is to define a function and its type separately, which is more akin to how it is done in a regular .hs file:

```
let readInt :: String -> Int; readInt = read
```

Neither is idiomatic Haskell, but that's because GHCi imposes quirky limitations on writing code and multi-line entry is strange. You could do this:

```
:{
let readInt :: String -> Int;
    readInt = read
:}
```

And that will get you close to the idiomatic Haskell definition. GHCi will however correctly compile my initial example if you put it in an .hs file and use `:load` or specify the file with `ghci ./somefile.hs`.

Answer (score 9):

When you type

```
read "456"
```

at the prompt, ghci has no information to find out which type you want. Do you want an `Int`, a `Bool`, `()`, `String`, ...

You need to tell it,

```
read "456" :: Int
```

so that it knows.

In a real programme, usually there is context which determines the required type, then it can be inferred and you don't need to manually supply a type. At the prompt, there is no context to help the inference.